# How can I specify a rotation direction when using AffineTransform?

Tags: java, rotation, affinetransform

For example, I need to rotate a rectangle in relation to its center on 45 degrees RIGHT. To have two buttons, one rotating right and other rotating left. What an AffineTransform.rotate() method call should look like? There is some "rotation vector" parameter, if I should use it, then how to specify a direction (right or left) with it?

Or it's just a matter of sign? 45 for right and -45 for left?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rotation direction depends on the sign of angle value: positive values imply right rotation whereas negative ones imply left rotation.